# Как в Unity прикрепить скрипт ко множеству объектов?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня в иерархии множество обьектов, около тысячи, я их все выделил и перетащил на них свой скрипт но во вкладке Inspector/Script/Object  написано None(GameObject), естественно перетаскивать в это поле по одному больше тысячи обьектов очень сложное занятие, так вот как мне сделать что бы Unity сам подцеплял объект? Я пробывал так, запросить все объекты с тэгом Player:

```
public GameObject obj;

void Start() {
    obj = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");
}
void Update() {
    Color32 color32 = new Color32 (4, 128, 192, 70);
    obj.GetComponent <Renderer> ().material.color = color32;
}
```

но почему то цвет менял лишь один объект.

Comment: я что-то не понял причем тут какие-то тысячи объектов и какой-то `None(GameObject)` в инспекторе чего-то. и  причем тут перетаскивание тысячи объектов куда-то непонятно куда...причем тут скрипт меняющий цвет..... можешь более понятно написать чего ты вообще хочешь сделать?)

Comment: В лучшем случае тебе нужен `FindGameObjectsWithTag`, в худшем - правильное описание проблемы и вопроса в целом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский цвет это просто для примера, вообще задача такая есть некое количество объектов(полигонов), и скрипт который рандомно меняет цвет каждого отдельного полигона, но мне каждый раз приходится  перетягивать по одному полигону в поле GameObject чтобы подцепить его к скрипту, вот я и хотел узнать есть ли способ проще

Comment: У тебя же, судя по прошлому вопросу, на каждом объекте свой скрипт. Странно как-то...... но вообще в таком случае, проще либо иметь список объектов `List<GameObject> obj` и использовав `FindGameObjectsWithTag` засунуть при старте эти объекты в список и уже манипулировать списком объектов.. либо при старте сгенерировать эти все объекты и также засунуть в список и манипулировать именно списком

Comment: Вам нужен Singleton Pattern вот видео
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=acn0ONc4G4M

Comment: @codename895431 не представляю как мне это поможет.

Comment: Не понятен вопрос, надо прикрепить скрипт к обьекту как компоненту, или в поле типа GameObject в скрипте прикрепить какой-то GameObject?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну вот перетащил я скрипт на тысячу объектов получается за каждым обьектом прикреплен экземпляр скрипта который работает отдельно от всех остальных, но он не будет работать пока я опять не кликну на объект и не перетащу его в поле GameObject того же скрипта который к нему прикреплен

Comment: и получается что мне нужно все время кликать на каждый объект по очереди и добавлять их в экземпляр скрипта за которым они же привязаны

Comment: @Jonathan `но он не будет работать пока я опять не кликну на объект и не перетащу его в поле GameObject того же скрипта который к нему прикреплен` - это какой-то бред. чтобы скрипт работал на самом себе - не нужно создавать поле `GameObject obj`  и перетаскивать самого себя в это поле. скрипт работает и так, как только его кинули на объект

Comment: @АлексейШиманский пфф все было так просто, а я заморочился, я думал что скрипту помимо привязки к объекту  обязательно нужно указать на объект непосредственно в коде. теперь все понятно obj. удалил и все сработало

Comment: @Jonathan ну если это какой-то другой объект, то да, нужно обозначить каким-либо из множества способов. А когда скрипт висит на объекте, то он (скрипт), по умолчанию указывает на своего родителя и работает с ним. Ты же не видел, чтобы у какого-нибудь `Renderer` или `CharacterController` было бы это поле? Это было бы слишком извращенно и не удобно для работы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да все верно, этого я и не мог понять, большое спасибо за то что обеснили.

Answer (score 0):

Адекватных вариантов 2:
Для первого необходимо, чтобы у всех этих объектов был одинаковый tag и после этого делаешь выборку с помощью метода:

```
FindGameObjectsWithTag
```

Во втором варианте ты просто делаешь perfab
После чего добавляешь 1000 раз (или сколько там у тебя объектов) этот перфаб в окно Hierarchy. В итоге все эти объекты будут связаны с твоим перфабом и любое изменение в перфабе приведёт к изменению во всех 1000 добавленных объектах